# Issue With Generating C++ Wrapper File For Python Code Using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have to use a C++ code in my Python Base Model. After my research, I came through SWIG, which creates C++ wrappers to integrate them into the Python code. My C++ code is extensive and I don't have time to convert it by using other options i.e., PyBind11, Cython etc.

So, after installing 'swig' in the CONDA Environment, I tried to create the wrapper file but failed to do so. I have given the detailed steps below which I tried and attached Screenshots for the errors I faced.

I executed the following steps which resulted into error:

Step - 1: Installed swig on my CONDA Environment by the command:
pip install swig

Screenshot for the successful Installation of the SWIG:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGrAh.png)

Step - 2: After the installation, I navigated to the directory where my CPP file is placed which I need to convert into a wrapper file to make it usable in my Python code.

Step - 3: Then I tried the following command to convert the CPP code file into a wrapper file.

swig -python implicit_feature_encoding.cpp -o implicit_wrapper.cpp

It resulted into the error as displayed in the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEJA9.png)

Note: At first, I tried it without creating a new wrapper file with name: 'implicit wrapper'. Later, I created the 'implicit_wrapper.cpp' file manually. However, the initial step is not being cleared.

I have also navigated through SWIG tutorials and came through the concept of creating Interface file. My C++ code is quite extensive with dependencies on three Header files, so if there is any other solution rather than creating an interface file, then suggest that too.

Thanks

Comment: The SWIG interface file need not be very large. It includes your header files (with `%include`) to get definitions from C++, but you will need to write stuff (such as typemaps) to tell SWIG how to handle those definitions.

Comment: "I have also navigated through SWIG tutorials and came through the concept of creating Interface file.".  Yes, you have to create an interface(.i) file.  Unless your functions are rather simple, with only inputs and standard C data types, you'll need more work to expose them properly.